# Kafka topics exist but not available from the brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have over 1,000 topics.  After an outage I find that only a handful of topics are showing up when listing the topics.  If I write to an existing but unavailable topic it says:

```sh
[2020-04-17 16:17:09,153] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {ONLP_NEWORDER_1428=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

However, after that subsequent writes are successful and the topic is available and shows up when I list all topics. Is there a trick I can do to get the topics to come back without having to write to it?

Answer (score 0):

**The delay in the kafka broker coming online can be due to one of these 2 scenarios:**

1. Delay in the Leader election
2. Kafka is configured to create topic when the first message is published.

**Scenario # 1: Delay in the election of leader:**

The error message - O**NLP_NEWORDER_1428=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE** signifies that the Leader node for the topic had not come online yet.

After an outage, the leader election takes some time (a few seconds to a few minutes, based on the configuration and network conditions)

Time taken for the leader election can be minimized by optimizing the kafka configuration.

**More information on optimizing kafka:**

https://www.confluent.io/wp-content/uploads/Optimizing-Your-Apache-Kafka-Deployment-1.pdf

**Scenario #2: Kafka configured to create topic when the first message is published**

By default, kafka is set to create a topic when the first message is published by the producer.

```
    This setting controls the automatic creation of topics.

    producer.auto.create.topics 


    The possible values for this setting are:

    allow-server-side  --> Default. Create topic on first message published

    client-side        --> Create topic at the first request from a consumer

    false              --> Do not create topics automatically
```

**(a) allow-server-side**

- This is the default setting
- This setting allows the Producer to create the topic automatically 
  if the broker's '**auto.create.topics.enable**' setting is set to **true**.

**(b) false**  -  does allow auto-topic creation.

**(c) Client-side**

Allows the creation of a topic when a consumer tries to consume a message.
(Supported on brokers > version 0.10.1.1 only)

**More information:**

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-487%3A+Client-side+Automatic+Topic+Creation+on+Producer

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/kafka-working-with-topics/content/creating_a_kafka_topic.html

Comment: That is not the problem.  All brokers are online.  Look at the example below.  The topic exists, but is not reachable. I produce to it, it throws the error and the is immediately available:

Comment: [/opt/apache/kafka/publix - uerxsecs@srxfxa01]$ ./describe.sh ONLP_ORDERLABEL_1171
[/opt/apache/kafka/publix - uerxsecs@srxfxa01]$ ./producer.sh ONLP_ORDERLABEL_1171
>1
[2020-04-20 15:52:51,532] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {ONLP_ORDERLABEL_1171=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>1
>2
>3
>^C

Comment: [/opt/apache/kafka/publix - uerxsecs@srxfxa01]$ ./producer.sh ONLP_ORDERLABEL_1171
>1
[2020-04-20 15:52:51,532] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {ONLP_ORDERLABEL_1171=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>1
>2
>3
>^C[/opt/apache/kafka/publix - uerxsecs@srxfxa01]$ ./describe.sh ONLP_ORDERLABEL_1171
Topic:ONLP_ORDERLABEL_1171      PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
        Topic: ONLP_ORDERLABEL_1171     Partition: 0    Leader: 202     Replicas: 202   Isr: 202

Comment: Hi Earl, can you check if Kafka is configured to automatically create a topic when a producer publishes a message?  If this is the setting, then the observed behavior could be due to it. I updated the answer description with details on this setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the leader reelection for the partitions, using the [kafka-leader-election.sh](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools) script or the Scala's [LeaderElectionCommand](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/LeaderElectionCommand.scala) object.

```
bin/kafka-leader-election.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092  --all-topic-partitions --election-type unclear
```